# How do I remove share menu suggestions?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, share-menu, file-sharing

Every time I use the share feature to share a photo in Android 7.1.1, it suggests people who are not in my contacts and contacts I have not spoken to in years. My phone can't be rooted and the suggestions I've found, such as disabling direct share, do not seem to be available in recent versions of Android. I don't want to share photos to so unsubscribe@spam.com email I used once or to some person I'm not in contact with.

How do I remove share suggestions or disable them entirely? I would rather just choose the app to share with and then select the recipient from within the app.

Edit: I've also found that older versions of Android had a feature to long-press and drag suggested share items to pin them to the top pf the menu. This no longer appears to work either. Please help get these people off my share menu.

[image: the stupid share menu where android randomly injects people you would never want to share images with in your entire life]

Answer (score 2):

> older versions of Android had a feature to long-press and drag suggested share items to pin them to the top of the menu

Some newer Android versions also have a feature to long-press on a contact name and hide it, e.g. it works on my Google Pixel 6 that runs on Android 12:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps important to be noted that the sharing menu on Google Photos is actually a *custom* share menu, not the Android's system share menu. Only by pressing "More" will show the system share menu.